# Python - numpy.delete doesn't work

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to delete a line from a .xyz file through numpy.delete () command, but is not working.

below is a part of the code problem. The code works without giving any error but the line is not deleted.

Thank you!

```
import numpy
import os

####################################################
a = numpy.loadtxt("0000_seg.xyz")
max_xyz = a.max(axis=0)
min_xyz = a.min(axis=0)
print max_xyz
print min_xyz
####################################################
ponto = numpy.loadtxt("0000_poucos.xyz")
####################################################

arquivos = os.listdir('/home/caye/Documentos/python/pontos')

print 'tamanho antes'
print len(ponto)

for arquivo in arquivos:
    try:
    for i in range(0,len(ponto)):
        for j in range(3):
            if ponto[i,j] > max_xyz[j]:
                print 'del max'
                numpy.delete(ponto, i)
            if ponto[i,j] < min_xyz[j]:
                print 'del min'
                numpy.delete(ponto, i)

    except:
        pass


print 'tamanho depois'
print len(ponto)
```

Comment: That `try:except:pass` is dangerous.  It can hide all kinds of unexpected errors.  What kind of error are you trying to capture or pass?

Comment: Iterative solutions like this are slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`numpy.delete()` is ***not*** an in-place operation, and returns a new copy of your array that has been operated on. As a result, `ponto` itself is never changed, you just return a changed copy of it and do nothing with it. Assign a new variable to your `numpy.delete()` statements, and print that. 
Also note `try-except-pass` is inherently evil and you could in fact have 100 things wrong in your code without knowing as it will hide all the errors.

You can find the documentation concerning `numpy.delete` which explains this behavior [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html).